# Unable to access ubuntu-gnome after reboot: cryptsetup:Unknown fstype; bad password or options?

Tags: boot, gnome

My laptop battery died last night on the train and this morning I plugged it in, booted and it was all sweet. Got to the desktop and the mouse could only move around, not click anything. I tried accessing the terminal with ctrl + alt + t with not success. So I held down the power button to reboot. Then when I've tried to login I get a variety of error messages.

Pressing F1 at the cryptsetup pw screen, before entering password I see:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysint
Volume group "ubuntu-gnome-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-gnome-vg
```

Please unlock disk sdc5_crypt"

If I type the correct password:

```
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: failed to connect no such file or directory
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad, Falling back on internal scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-gnome-vg" using metadata type lvm2
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: failed to connect no such file or directory
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad, Falling back on internal scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-gnome-vg" now active.
cryptsetup:Unknown fstype; bad password or options?
device-mapper: remove ioctl on sdc5_crypt failed: Device or resource busy
```

The last line repeats a lot, followed by intermittent

```
Device sdc5_crypt is still in use
```

After a while it continuously prints

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysint
```

until finally it prints

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args
 check root delay
 check root
- Missing modules
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Which drops to busy box prompt.

The other day I had a bad superblock in /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root which I fixed with fsck. This one isn't so easy. The ubuntu--gnome--vg-root is in /dev/mapper though.

I have tried booting with an earlier kernal with no success.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I finally found a solution all on my own. I made a live usb and tried mounting the disk from it. I was getting very similar errors to normal - that my filesystem type was unknown (LVM2_member or something). I had the hunch to try perform an fsck on the linux volume from within the liveusb environment, this found many errors. I rebooted it and voila! It worked.

Hope this helps someone in need later!